# How to override css class without touching the HTML?

Tags: css

I wrote a very simple codepen and tried to overide a css class inside an h1 element, trying to do so with ONLY css.

Is it even possible, I can add a div around the H1 but I can't touch the H1 html, is that possible?

[override H1 css with surrounding div](http://codepen.io/Satearn/pen/grWjGJ)

```
  [1]: http://codepen.io/Satearn/pen/grWjGJ
```

```js
.b2
{color:green;}
.a1
{color:red;}
```

```html
<div class="b2">
 <h1 class="a1">Hello</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to target specificly even then. You are almost right, but in your selector you need to add a space. If you dont add that space it will look for both classes in one element. (so in your div it will seek for as well `.b1` as `. a1`, which doesn't excist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override a CSS rule, you need to either **put it after the original rule**, or **use a higher [specificity](https://specificity.keegan.st/)** for the new rule.

Bear in mind, in both cases you need to select the same element, otherwise **the child element rules will always have higher priority**.

In your case, you're selecting different elements, so the override rule would be simple:

```
.a1 {color:green;}
```

or, if you want to override the color only when the parent is `.b2`:

```
.b2 .a1 {color:green;}
```

Not sure if `.b2.a1` in your CodePen is a typo, but that will only select elements that have both `b2` and `a1` classes, like `<div class="b2 a1"></div>`.

Comment: Stupid me...TYPO...I'm struggling with Drupal Display suite extras, so complicated I get tired and miss the obvious..!

Comment: It happens to everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course it's possible.  You just need to change your selector to this:

```
.b2 .a1 {color:green;}
```

That is, add a space.

This selector you had: `.b2.a1` (without the space) applies to every element which has *both* classes which is not what you want in your case.

This selector, however: `.b2 .a1` (with a space) applies to any element whose class is a1 *and* is a descendant of any element which has the .b2 class - which is exactly what you need.

Comment: Ah, you wrote pretty much everything while I was writing mine. +1 :)